# Ansible: Could not locate file in lookup

Tags: linux, rhel, ansible, yaml

I wrote a playbook to deploy my ssh keys across multiple instances. This my playbook, but I am experiencing some problems with it. I already created my ssh keys from my local instance. Please see below.

[image: This is my YAML file]

I confirmed, and I was able to cat /export/home/staff/kadutut/.ssh/id_rsa.pub.

[image: This is when it fails]

Comment: Do not put binary images instead of the code.

Comment: Please post text as text. Images of text are hard to read, especially by blind people, but also for others.

Answer (score 1):

The *lookup* plugin *file* reads the files from the controller/master. The error says: *' The user running the playbook is not able to read the file'*.  The directory *.ssh* has permissions '0700'. Wild guess: the user is not able to read this directory? It's a good idea to create a storage or database of public keys.

Comment: Thank you! that actually worked

Comment: You're welcome! Update the question and replace the images with the code. Make it [mre](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) e.g. module *authorized_key* is not needed to reproduce the problem. Simple *debug* would serve the purpose as well. Make it minimal and reproducible, please!